# Borel algebra by Fell topology

Tags: probability, general-topology, measure-theory, random-variables

I am studying how to randomize a finite set in $\mathbb{R}^d$. More specifically, I want to find a simple way to use mathemaical language to discrible a "random set". After searching literature, following two concepts (actually two different approaches of this "random set") came to me.

1. Random Finite Set [Appendix F, [Statistical Multisource-Multitarget Information Fusion](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9100086)]: mathematically speaking, a measurable mapping from a probability space to the hyperspace of $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Here $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is all finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, and "hyperspace" means the space of closed subsets. Then this hyperspace is topologized by using Fell-Matheron "hit-or-miss" topology (by defining sub-base of the topology, which we will not focus on). Fortunately, this topology of hyperspace is equivalent to the one generated by [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).
2. Finite Point Process (Section 5.3, [An Introduction to the
   Theory of Point Processes: Volume I: Elementary
   Theory and Methods, Second Edition](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97277)): a finite point process in $\mathbb{R^d}$ can be defined by a probability distribution $\{p_n\}$ on the nonnegative integers and a family of symmetric probability distributions $\Pi_n^{\text {sym }}(\cdot)$ on $\mathcal{B}^{(n)}, n \geq 1$, where $\mathcal{B}^{(n)}$ is the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{R}^d$.

Now I am considering two difference of these two concepts (or the consistency of them). Basically, I do not know what does the Borel algebra generated by Fell topology likes like especially when we fix the cardinality of sets. Will it in some way "include" the Borel algebra in the product space?

I can not see it very clearly even only considering $\mathbb{R}^2$ and sets only having two distinct points. Any comment helps.